# Confused about flight distance and flight time

Tags: commercial-aviation, navigation

I'm having a hard time understanding how the flight times of these flight are so different.

I looked up PDX (Portland, Or) to DEN (Denver, Co) is roughly 923 miles, with a flight time of 2h30m to DEN and 2h45m to PDX.

BUR (Burbank, Can) to PDX is 831 miles with a flight time of 3h30m.

How is a longer distance flight take less time?

All Southwest, they only have 737-700, 737-800, and 737-800 MAX.  Referring too only non-stop flights.

[image: PDX to DEN]

[image: BUR to PDX]

Comment: What planes were being used? How many stops did the flights have?

Comment: Alaska Airlines 317 from BUR to PDX takes typically a little over 2 hours on a B737 according to [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ASA317).

Comment: Where did you get these times from? Are they just the airborne time or are they gate-to-gate? Are they the same airline, the same aircraft type?

Comment: Departure delays getting out of a small, non-primary airport in SoCal can be significant.

Comment: Don't you see "1 stop - no plane change" on BUR to PDX?

Answer (score 1):

Using [SimBrief](https://www.simbrief.com/), I filed two example flight plans: One from PDX to DEN and one from BUR to PDX. As you can see in the images below, the former route has a continuous light tailwind, while the latter route has a moderate crosswind. Despite this, using an A320 as our reference, BUR to PDX takes 17 minutes *less* than PDX to DEN. Please verify where you got your information from.

*PDX to DEN. Note the "dashes" that indicate wind direction and velocity.*
[image]

*BUR to PDX.*
[image]